# create search index on JSON column using specific tablespace

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to create search index using a specific tablespace like
CREATE SEARCH INDEX EX_INVOICE_LINE_ITEM_ADDITIONAL_INFO ON EX_INVOICE_LINE_ITEM(ADDITIONAL_INFO) *TABLESPACE MX_DATA* FOR JSON

without the tablespace clause it will work but I want to mention the tablespace explicitly.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported.